# Выпадающий список

Tags: php

Добрый день.

У меня возникла следующая проблема. Есть выпадающий список и текстовое поле, при выборе элемента из списка ID его попадает в текстовое поле. Как мне считать ID из текстового поля, занести в переменную и потом в запрос?

```
<?php
$query_fac  = mysql_query("SELECT Id_Faculty,Faculty_Name FROM Faculty");
$result_fac = mysql_fetch_array($query_fac);
?>
<body onload="document.getElementById('Id_Fac').value = document.getElementById('Fac_Name').value">

<table>
    <form action="new_contract.php" method="post">
        <tr>
            <td>Факультет :</td>
            <td>
                <select onchange="document.getElementById('Id_Fac').value = this.value"
                id="Fac_Name" selected>
                <?php
                do {
                    printf("<option value='%s'>%s</option>", $result_fac['Id_Faculty'], $result_fac['Faculty_Name']);
                } while ($result_fac = mysql_fetch_array($query_fac));
                mysql_free_result($query_fac);
                ?>
                 </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="Id_Faculty" id="Id_Fac" size="4" />
            </td>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php
        $query_spec  = mysql_query("SELECT Full_Spec_Name FROM Speciality WHERE Id_Faculty =");
        $result_spec = mysql_fetch_array($query_spec);
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td>Специальность :</td>
            <td>
                <select>
                <?php
                do {
                    printf("<option >%s</option>", $result_spec['Full_Spec_Name']);
                } while ($result_spec = mysql_fetch_array($query_spec));
                ?>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

Ну что у вас получилось что то?

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, пример кода. Тогда, я думаю, смогу Вам помочь.

Comment: Код скидывается в виде каши какой-то, в тэги форматирования здесь можно как-то заключить код?

Comment: А как кидать то? Ответить на вопрос не могу пишут не хватает очков,если в комментарии кидают -400 символов как быть?

Comment: Нужно нажать кнопку 101010, чтобы код автоматом отформатировался как положено!

Comment: Я кинул код, посмотрите, пожалуйста, и помогите, чем сможете.

Comment: Под текстовым полем Вы подразумеваете тег input с id="Id_Fac"?

Comment: Да, оно самое.

Comment: Ок, сейчас постараюсь Вам помочь!

Comment: `#Id_Fac` тут лишнее вообще. У вас значением `#Fac_Name` при выборе как раз и будет id, и на сервер полетит именно он.

Answer (score 1):

У вас нарушены причинно-следственные связи :) Вашу задачу можно разбить на подзадачи:

1. Показать форму (это сделано)
2. Подгружать данные сервера при выборе элементов формы.(это делается через AJAX)

Дабы избежать ненужных вопросов советую почитать:

1. [Как работает РНР, где он выполняется?](http://phpfaq.ru/na_tanke#where)
2. [jquery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) собственно если там будет не ясно, этот же запрос можно вбить в гугл, сразу получишь гору примеров.

Comment: Я дал ссылку, где читать, ничего сложного и страшного в этом "AJAX" нету, есть куча примеров, как их получить я тоже написал. Если вы сами не научитесь - никто за вас научиться не сможет.

Comment: Jquery знаю и JS,ща гляну что из себя представляет ajax,спасибо !

Comment: Решил проблему без Ajax!

Comment: Сразу все подгружаете с формой ? тоже вариант.

Comment: Я повесил на Select событие onChange  с отправкой формы,и потом из Post считал Id и занес в переменную!

Comment: На дворе 2012 год, а вы ... гость из прошлого :)

З.Ы. Сейчас уже пОшло постоянно перегружать форму при ее заполнении.

Comment: Ну я не специалист) Не со всем еще сталкивался!